# Service Worker FechtEvent.respondWith response is null on iOS 12.1 Safari

Tags: ios, safari, service-worker

I can download the website using the service Worker on Android Chrome, macOS Chrome as well as Safari and on Windows Chrome for offline use. When I try to download the website to **iOS 12.1 Safari** it works first. But when I close Safari, go offline and reopen Safari, I get the following **error message**:

> Safari can't open the Site.
>
> Error: "FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: TypeError: There
> seems to be no connection to the Internet."
>
> ==== AND in the console ====
>
> FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: Returned response is null

Below you can see the scripts in text form. Unfortunately, I can hardly report anything about the problem, because I don't understand it and hope for some knowledgeable people :)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Offline App</h1>
</body>
<script>
    if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function (registration) {
            console.log('Service Worker Registered');
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

sw.js

```
/*
 Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at
 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
*/

importScripts('cache-polyfill.js');

var CACHE_VERSION = 1;
var CURRENT_CACHES = {
    prefetch: 'prefetch-cache-v' + CACHE_VERSION
};

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    var now = Date.now();

    var urlsToPrefetch = [
        '/pwa/index.html'
    ];

    console.log('Handling install event. Resources to prefetch:', urlsToPrefetch);

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.prefetch).then(function(cache) {
            var cachePromises = urlsToPrefetch.map(function(urlToPrefetch) {
                var url = new URL(urlToPrefetch, location.href);
                url.search += (url.search ? '&' : '?') + 'cache-bust=' + now;

                var request = new Request(url, {mode: 'no-cors'});
                return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
                    if (response.status >= 400) {
                        throw new Error('request for ' + urlToPrefetch +
                            ' failed with status ' + response.statusText);
                    }

                    return cache.put(urlToPrefetch, response);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.error('Not caching ' + urlToPrefetch + ' due to ' + error);
                });
            });

            return Promise.all(cachePromises).then(function() {
                console.log('Pre-fetching complete.');
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Pre-fetching failed:', error);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    var expectedCacheNames = Object.keys(CURRENT_CACHES).map(function(key) {
        return CURRENT_CACHES[key];
    });

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                    if (expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
                        console.log('Deleting out of date cache:', cacheName);
                        return caches.delete(cacheName);
                    }
                })
            );
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if (!navigator.onLine) {

        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                if (response) {

                    return response;
                }

                console.log('No response found in cache. About to fetch from network...');

                return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                    console.log('Response from network is:', response);

                    return response;
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('Fetching failed:', error);
                    throw error;
                });
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tested the script on several iphones (12.0, 12.0.1 (16A404) as well as 12.1(16B92)) And on all of them I could download the web app and open it offline again. I currently suspect that on iphones that have the following settings enabled the PWA has problems finding the cache again: 1. Don't allow cache and 2. Restricted iphone (parental control) After I allowed the cache to work, it still didn't work. I couldn't disable the restricted mode because the owner doesn't know the code anymore.

Comment: I figured out, that hosting the site via xampp and visiting it with my phone (iOS 12.1.1) I can visit it offline. When served over my server with nginx I also get the same error you mentioned. I don't have a solution yet, but maybe that information can help you.

Comment: Did you ever found the solution to this or what the problem was? I've been stuck for days with this error and I haven't found a solution on where to start looking.

Comment: Sorry until now no solution for this found. It is happend only on one device, so i decide to go on. If you want you can try to reset your iphone. Until now my guess is a failure in the privacy configuration in the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and the following steps resolved it for me:

- Remove the app from the home screen.
- [Clear the cache in Mobile Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphacc5f0202/ios).
- Re-add the app to the home screen.

Answer (score -1):

After clearing Web cache it working fine for me ...

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to the question? Then please rephrase to make it more obvious.