# [PWA][NEXT.JS][iOS] I sometimes cannot get data from server. The error message is FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: no-response: no-response

Tags: safari, progressive-web-apps, next.js13

My PWA app sometimes cannot get data from server. It shows errors like:

FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: no-response: no-response
Fetch API cannot load
no internet connection

[[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.c[image]om/ZcBm4.png)

But if we reload the page, it could get data normally. And these bugs only happened in Safari. It is working well in Chrome or window devices.

I reference some page. But I don't know these bugs caused by BE settings (CORS) or Safari.

My devices I am testing is iPhone XS, iOS 14.4
And I am using the newest 'next-pwa' version which means the workbox version is 6.5.4

```
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.5.4",
"workbox-window": "^6.5.4"
```

Referenced Pages:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1730

https://www.adro.codes/vault/pwa-fetch-respondwith-error-safari

[Service Worker FechtEvent.respondWith response is null on iOS 12.1 Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431195/service-worker-fechtevent-respondwith-response-is-null-on-ios-12-1-safari)